# Line-by-line profiling of Julia code possible?

Tags: julia

I have some Julia functions that are several hundreds of lines long that I would like to profile so that I can then work on optimizing the code.

I am aware of the *BenchmarkTools* package which allows the overall execution time and memory consumption of a function to be measured using `@btime` or `@benchmark`. But those functions tell me nothing about where inside the functions the bottlenecks are. So my first step would have to be using some tool to identify which parts of the code are slow.

In Matlab for instance there is a very nice built-in profiler which runs a script/function and then reports the time spent on every line of the code. Similarly in Python there is a module called *line_profiler* which can produce a line-by-line report showing how much time was spent on every single line of a function.

What I’m looking for is simply a line-by-line report showing the total time spent on each line of code and how many times a particular piece of code was called.

Is there such a functionality in Julia? Either built-in or via some third-party package.

Comment: Yes it has a profiling module, there are also IDE’s with Profiling built in available in this link - https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/profile/

Comment: @AWebb But can the output of Profile.print() be formatted to show time spent on each line of code? From what I can see in their examples the printout obtained from Profile does not show the time spent per line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [Profiling](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/profile/) chapter in Julia docs with all the necessary info.

Also, you can use [ProfileView.jl](https://github.com/timholy/ProfileView.jl) or similar packages for visual exploration of the profiled code.

And, not exactly profiling, but very useful in practice package is [TimerOutputs.jl](https://github.com/KristofferC/TimerOutputs.jl)

UPD: Since Julia is a compiling language it makes no sense to measure timing of individual lines, since the actual code that is executed can be very different from what is written in Julia.

For example following julia code

```
function f()
    x = 0
    for i in 0:100_000_000
        x += i
    end

    x
end
```

is lowered to

```
julia> @code_llvm f()
;  @ REPL[8]:1 within `f'
define i64 @julia_f_594() {
top:
;  @ REPL[8]:7 within `f'
  ret i64 5000000050000000
}
```

I.e. there is no loop at all. This is why instead of execution time proxy metric of how often a line appears in the set of all backtraces is used. Of course, it is not the same as the execution time, but it gives a good approximation of where the bottleneck is because lines with long execution time appear in backtraces more often.

Comment: I have looked at the Profiling documentation and previously experimented with the various visualizers they list. From what I can tell they mostly produce colorful “flame graphs” figures with little to no explanation in the documentation as to how they should be interpreted. That is not what I’m looking for.

Essentially I want to run the @time function on every line of my code and have a text-based output correlating every line of my code to an execution time. Is this possible using the Profiling tool? I cannot see any mentioning of that in the docs.

Comment: There are many other reasons to use statistical (aka, sampling) profiling. In Matlab, most of the "real work" is done in C code that is not accessible to their profiler; that means that the overhead of line-by-line profiling doesn't really matter because you're not actually profiling the performance-sensitive code anyway. In Julia, you are profiling the performance-sensitive code, so it's much more important that the profiler stay out of the way. Most of the high-performance language world has switched over to sampling profilers, just as is done in Julia.

Comment: > little to no explanation in the documentation as to how they should be interpreted
IMO, https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/profile/ is pretty detailed about how to interpret the results. But if specific things aren't clear, please file an issue!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)#Statistical_profilers in case you didn't follow that link.

Comment: I am not sure what this meant : "This is why instead of execution time proxy metric of how often a line appears in the set of all backtraces is used" but is there a function that searches backtraces (I do not know what backtraces are but anything that shows where the bottlenecks are could be helpful)

Answer (score 1):

[OwnTime.jl](https://github.com/DevJac/OwnTime.jl). Doesn't do call counts though, but it should be easy to add.